# Show that this curve is regular

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves

Given that $\beta$ is parametrised by arc length (with strictly positive curvature), show that the curve $\alpha (s) = \beta (s) - s \beta{'}(s)$ is a regular curve. To show that it's regular I have to show that $|| \alpha'(s) || > 0$ for all $s$. To try to do this I found the derivative of $\alpha$ to be $$\alpha'(s) = \beta'(s) - \beta'(s) - s\beta''(s) = -s\beta''(s) =  -s\kappa(s)N(s)$$
where $\kappa$ and $N$ are the curvature and normal vector of $\beta$. My problem is now where to go from here. It is never stated whether or not the interval being worked with contains $0$ or not. If it does, clearly $\alpha'(0) = 0$ so that $\alpha$ is not regular.

Is my work up until this point correct, or is the question just wrong? The question was given to me by another student of the same course, so it may have been written down incorrectly.

Comment: I assume your curves are planar, note space curves, isn't it ?

Comment: I think they are space curves, as part (b) of the problem asks to prove that $\beta$ is a cylindrical helix if $\alpha$ is planar. It was not specified when I received the question, but given part (b) I think it's safe to assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are space curves.

Comment: Do you know Serret-Frenet formulas (for 3D) ?

Comment: Yes I know them.

Comment: You’re right. It’s regular for $s\ne 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin So my working was all correct up until that point? I assume the original question must have specified that $s \neq 0$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, your calculation is fine.